# Why DataSource not work with PreparedStatement in JSP?

Tags: jsp, prepared-statement, datasource

I realized the connection DataSource with createstatement but I have problems with PreparedStatement. Error: **java.lang.NullPointerException**

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*, javax.sql.*, javax.naming.*,java.sql.PreparedStatement;"%>

DataSource ds;
Connection con= null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;


String sql = "select * from test where...";

String name= request.getParameter("name");


if((!(name.equals(null))
{
try{
Context context = new InitialContext();
ds =  (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/DataSourceConn");
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, name);

rs = ps.executeQuery();
if(rs.next())
{ 
userdbName = rs.getString("name");
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following code to actually make the `connection` instead of the `null`:

```
con = ds.getConnection();
```

like this

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
ds =  (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/DataSourceConn");
con = ds.getConnection();
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, name);
```